# Conceptual Explanation of Accumulation Point and How to Find them?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, limits, analysis

I'm having a difficult time understanding what an accumulation point is and how to find it. My textbook uses the following definition:

"An accumulation point of a nonempty set $E$ of real numbers is an extended real number a such that every neighborhood of a contains a point of $E$ not equal to $a$."

I've searched online for definitions that are easier to understand, but still cannot conceptualize. And how are accumulation points different from limit points? Lastly, how would I go about finding APs? Specifically for the set:

$$
\left\{\frac{2}{m} - \frac{3}{n} \colon m, n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}
$$
I think $-1$ and $0$ would be APs but I have no idea how to prove that?

Comment: Your definition of accumulation point agrees with the standard definition of limit point.  Some authors use the two terms differently so that they actually mean different things.  Be careful and consult your text.

Comment: The concept can best be understood via the usual meaning of accumulation. If $c$ is an accumulation point of set $A$ then many members of $A$ are lying near $c$ or are accumulated/clustered near $c$. The term cluster point is also used for the same concept.

Comment: Using the definition in your question you can easily show that if $c$ is a accumulation point of $A$ then every neighborhood of $c$ contains infinitely many points of $A$.

Answer (score 2):

A point $x$ is a limit point of $E$ if whenever you draw a ball around $x$, you can find another point in $E$ that is not equal to $x$ inside the ball. Hence by drawing multiple balls by shrinking the radius, you can construct a sequence of points in $E$ not equal to $x$ that converges to $x$ ,which is an intuitive reason why it is called a limit point. Also, inside each such ball, you should be able to find infinitly many points of $E$.

The set of limit points should be

$$\{ 0\} \cup \left\{  \frac2m : m \in \mathbb{N}\right\} \cup \left\{  -\frac3n : n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}. $$

$0$ is a limit point since $$\lim\limits_{m \to \infty} \left[\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac2m-\frac3n\right)\right] = 0$$

Also, for any $m \in \mathbb{N}$, $\frac2m$ is a limit point since $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac2m - \frac3n \right)=\frac2m.$$

For any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $-\frac3n$ is a limit point since

$$\lim_{m \to \infty} \left(\frac2m - \frac3n \right)=-\frac3n.$$

For points that are bigger than $2$ or smaller than $-3$, it should be clear that they are not limit points.

Now suppose a point $x$ satisfies $$\frac2{m+1} < x< \frac2m$$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$.

Notice that $\left( \frac2{m+1} , \frac{x + \frac2m}{2} \right)$ and $\cup_{i=1}^m  \left[\cup_{n=1}^\infty\{\frac2i-\frac3n\}\right]$ can only intersect at finitely many points since for each $i$, $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac2i - \frac3n \right)=\frac2i$ and we only have to consider finitely many $i$.  This implies that $\left( \frac2{m+1} , \frac{x + \frac2m}{2} \right)$  intersect with your original set finitely many times since the other points are less than $\frac{2}{m+1}$. Hence, such $x$ cannot be a limit point. Similar argument can be used for the other negative values.

Comment: This is so helpful thank you so much!!! You give a very clear explanation and I clearly understand why the set are limit points.
Would you be able to clarify please why you are choosing x the way you do and how you chose 2/m+1? thank you!

Comment: I was trying to illustrate that there is no limit point between $\frac2m$ and $\frac2{m+1}$. I have claimed that for positive numbers, they are of the form of $\frac2m$ and I want to make sure that I didn't miss out any other point. So I check any positive number that are between those two numbers is not a limit point.